# AWS Cloudwatch, S3 and Logging Solution Assistance

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, amazon-cloudwatch

We have thousands of EC2 instances pushing logs to various Cloudwatch Log Groups & Stream.
However, because of the huge amount of logs, we are not able to download them efficiently.
What other architecture can we use so that we can store the logs from those instances which is also easily downloadable ?
Thank you in advance !

Comment: Store them in S3 and then in Deep Archive? not sure what is the issue?

Comment: The problem is how to I send them to S3 with a continuous integration enabled ? The logs are flowing in real time and S3 does not allow us to append.

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear how to send logs to s3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common way of coppying logs to S3 from CloudWatch Logs in **real-time** is through [CloudWatch Logs Subscription Filter for Firehose](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/SubscriptionFilters.html#FirehoseExample):

> In this example, you'll create a CloudWatch Logs subscription that **sends any incoming log events** that match your defined filters to your Amazon Kinesis Data Firehose delivery stream.

In the firehose stream you would set [S3 destination](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/create-destination.html#create-destination-s3),

Comment: I tried this approach, but the main problem is that the logs from multiple streams are delivered to a single file from Firehose and also present in a Json format. How can we resolve this ?

Comment: @KarthikRaoV You can't, unless you stream to lambda and do any type of log event transformations and distribution to different buckets using your function.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the response. It was helpful. Have a good day ahead !